# How to connect one name tag to multiple row in Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm reading an Excel file to an Access table but im stuck with normalizing the table 
from this:

```
ALPHA
3110 JOT01E000004506 okt.
3110 JOT01E000004506 nov.
3110 JOT01E000004506 dec.
---empty row --
BETA
3112 JOT01E000004506 okt.
3112 JOT01E000004506 nov.
3112 JOT01E000004506 dec.
```

To This:

```
ALPHA 3110 JOT01E000004506 okt.
ALPHA 3110 JOT01E000004506 nov.
ALPHA 3110 JOT01E000004506 dec.
BETA  3112 JOT01E000004506 okt.
BETA  3112 JOT01E000004506 nov.
BETA  3112 JOT01E000004506 dec.
```

Comment: are you working in access or in excel?

Comment: Do you need VBA or could you do this with a helper column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that MS Access treats data as an unordered set unless otherwise specified using an `order by` clause within a query.

As such, when importing data from an external file into an MS Access table, you cannot rely on the order of the records in the resulting table matching those in the source file.

Therefore, as in your case, if your data is wholly dependent upon the sequence in which certain identifier rows are encountered in the dataset, I would suggest using VBA to iterate over each row in the Excel spreadsheet in sequence, test for the presence of the 'identifier' row and assign its value to a variable, and then add each individual record to your target table.

Here is a draft outline of such a program:

```
Function ImportData(strXLS As String)

    Dim dbsCdb As DAO.Database
    Dim rstRs1 As DAO.Recordset

    Dim xlsApp As Excel.Application
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim strTag As String
    Dim strTmp As String

    Set xlsApp = New Excel.Application
    Set dbsCdb = CurrentDb
    Set rstRs1 = dbsCdb.OpenRecordset("Table1")

    With xlsApp
        With .Workbooks.Open(strXLS)
            With .Worksheets("Sheet1")
                strTag = .Cells(1, 1)
                lngRow = 2
                Do Until strTag = vbNullString
                    strTmp = .Cells(lngRow, 1)
                    If strTmp = vbNullString Then
                        lngRow = lngRow + 1
                        strTag = .Cells(lngRow, 1)
                    Else
                        rstRs1.AddNew
                        rstRs1("Tag") = strTag
                        rstRs1("Field1") = .Cells(lngRow, 2)
                        rstRs1("Field2") = .Cells(lngRow, 3)
                        rstRs1("Field3") = .Cells(lngRow, 4)
                        rstRs1.Update
                    End If
                    lngRow = lngRow + 1
                Loop
            End With
            .Close
        End With
        .Quit
    End With

    rstRs1.Close
    Set rstRs1 = Nothing
    Set dbsCdb = Nothing
    Set xlsApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Some prerequisites:

- Add a reference to `Microsoft Excel ##.0 Object Library`
- Excel data is held in a worksheet called `Sheet1`
- First 'tag' appears in cell `A1`
- Target Access table is call `Table1`
- MS Access `Table1` contains 4 fields: `Tag`, `Field1`, `Field2`, `Field3`.

Supply with path to the Excel workbook, e.g.:

```
ImportData "C:\YourExcelFile.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could import them into a table with an autonumber `ID`, so you get something like so

[image]

Then you could use the following SQL to give the desired output

```
SELECT 
p.new_category,
z.txtField1,
z.txtField2,
z.ID,
p.new_id
FROM tblSource as z
left join
(
SELECT 
(select x.txtField1 from tblSource as x where x.ID=y.id+1) as new_ID,
y.txtField1 as new_category
FROM tblSource as y
WHERE (((y.[txtfield2]) Is Null))
) as p
on 
z.txtfield1=p.new_ID
where z.txtfield2 is not null
order by z.id
```

this gives

[image]

I used the following in Access to import the data

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
             acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
             "tblSource", _
             "C:\Databases\excel_test.xlsx", _
             True
```

My table is designed as follows

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot rely on the data being imported in the same order in which it appears in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Use it from Access and how you are connecting to the excel workbook as the source then rather than import.  I'll add to answer

Comment: How is it getting imported?

Comment: Using the Excel ActiveX object model.

Comment: Can you show that in your original post, so we can see.

Comment: @LeeMac try using the `transferspreadsheet` method instead into a table already created to hold the data with an autonumber  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferspreadsheet

Comment: As noted, you cannot rely on the order of the data being retained using this method - MS Access deals in unordered sets.

Comment: If you import line by line to a table with an autonumber, this should be avoidable as it will occur in the Excel order and the autonumber will be applied, then the sql solution would apply.  Where the SQL could be the population of the final table.

Comment: Where are you importing line by line?

Comment: Your code is, so you could add an autonumber to the table and then use SQL to manipulate it.

Comment: @LeeMac Apologies.  I misread your answer as the original post, hence yesterday's confusion :o)  It was a long day.